# JS - replaceWith not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to update a div with a static value but [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) seems to be less collaborative than I was thinking. 
This is the function:

```
updatePeopleNumber: function(peopleNumber) {
   var numberItem = jQuery("#visitors-container");
   numberItem.find("vn").replaceWith(peopleNumber);
}
```

Again: peopleNumber is a static value set right before this function is called. This is the HTML:

```
<div id="row-2" class="row">
        <div id="visitors-container">
            <div id="visitors-number" class="vn"><?php echo getPeopleNumber(); ?></div>
            <div id="visitors-text">visitors today</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The PHP code is there for security reasons: if no value is set, then the PHP comes in. But I need the js code to replace the value in the div with peopleNumber... 
If someone is wondering: no, deleting the PHP code doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: You forgot the dot for the class name `numberItem.find(".vn")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas you don't use the returned value of the replaceWith method you can use instead of it the [jquery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) setter

```
  numberItem.find(".vn").html(peopleNumber);
```

Also you missed the dot for the class name `numberItem.find(".vn")`

Comment: bingo. You know what's funny? That I've made two functions to refresh two different divs: the first was working like a charm and the second wasn't. Guess what I was using in the first -.-

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
<div id="row-2" class="row">
    <div id="visitors-container">
        <div id="visitors-number" class="vn"><span><?php echo getPeopleNumber(); ?></span></div>
        <div id="visitors-text">visitors today</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#visitors-number').find("span").text(peopleNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your selector at `find("vn")`. You forgot the class selector `.`.

```
updatePeopleNumber: function(peopleNumber) {
   var numberItem = jQuery("#visitors-container");
   numberItem.find(".vn").replaceWith(peopleNumber);
}
```